# Delay on every cicle of an CSS animation

Tags: css, html, css-animations

I'm trying to emulate an animation that was made using the HTML5 canvas tag and JavaScript. I am using only HTML5 and CSS, and I feel like I am close to do it, but (maybe among other things) I need to set a delay between cycles (I guess), so the button I am using could be displayed on it's own for a brief period of time.

The original button animation may be found in [here](https://www.hpmagicwords.com.br/)

```css
body {
  margin: 80px;
}
.ripples {
  position: relative;
}
.ripple {
  border: 1px solid #B82679;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
/*/*animation: name duration timing-function delay iteration-count direction fill-mode play-state;*/

.ripple-1 {
  animation: ripple 1s linear infinite ;

}
.ripple-2 {
  animation: ripple 1s linear infinite .8s;

 }

@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  5%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ripples">  
  <div class="ripple ripple-1"> </div>
  <div class="ripple ripple-2"></div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/maRO9.png"/>
</div>
```

[My icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maRO9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.ripple-1 {
  animation: ripple 2s linear infinite ;

}
.ripple-2 {
  animation: ripple 2s linear infinite .45s;

 }

@-webkit-keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

something like that, basically your animation is going from 0% to 40%, the rest of animation is that delay before it starts again. just tweak duration a bit to your liking. hope it helps

#### EDIT:

you can center it like so
CSS:

```
.ripples {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/maRO9.png") center no-repeat;
}

.ripple {
  border: 1px solid #B82679;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div class="ripples">
  <div class="ripple ripple-1"> </div>
  <div class="ripple ripple-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked really great! I was wondering how can I center the elements, I can center the button but not the ripples.